# How to integrate vue with custom routing into an existing regular website?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I’d like to integrate vue into a existing webproject. In detail I want to use vue to integrate data from www.autoscout24.de into a website which basically uses Modx-cms, which means that the routing generally takes place inside Modx. With vue I want to realize a search form which I can integrate anywhere inside the existing website. The results should display under something like domain.tld/cars and a single car should be displayed at something like domain.tld/cars/cardetails#8574746

So regarding the routing I guess /cars and /cars/cardetails will be regular sites of the cms (vue only shows the data) but the Hashtag-routing for cardetails will be handled by vue, right?

As the App (should I call it three different apps?) will not be a SAP how can I pass data between the search form, /cars and /cars/cardetails#xyz? Is local storage the way to go?

Is that the right approach. Maybe my approach is even completely wrong, as I am new to vue?

Some further details regarding the app:
The searchform will react to every user input with a request to the Graph QL-Api in order to show the user live how many results he will get. Above the form there will be a teaser with around 10 random cars. After submitting the form the user is directed to /cars where he receives his resultslist (photos of the cars + some quick information). Above the list I want to show the filters so the user can adjust the resultslist. When the user clicks on the car he will get directed to /cars/cardetails#xyz where xyz is the id of the car in order to fetch the cardetails from the api via js/graphql.

Kind regards

Here are some screens to illustrate it. The parts which should be realized with vue are marked red.

[image]

Comment: Generally, you should only have Vue handle the routing if you are building an SPA, otherwise you'll want to stick to only modifying the query string or fragment part of the URL within Vue, as it will conflict with whatever routing you have set up with Modx. You could also use Vue Router with hash mode. How do you expect the Vue app to behave? Please provide more concrete details and describe what you've already tried.

Comment: I didn't start developing yet as I wanted to gather some informations/experiences before in order to prevent me from running to the completely wrong direction as I am new to vue.

I just updated the information above and added some more screens for clarification.

Thanks in advance!